# loading csv file from S3 in neo4j graphdb

Tags: amazon-s3, neo4j, load-csv

I am seeking some suggestion about loading csv files from s3 bucket to neo4j  graphdb. In S3 bucket the files are in csv.gz format. I need to import them  into my neo4j graph db which is in ec2 instance.

```
1. Is there any direct way to load csv.gz into neo4j db without unzipping it ?
2. can I set/add s3 bucket path into neo4j.conf  file at neo4j.dbms.directory  which is by default neo4j/import ?
```

kindly help me to suggest some idea to load files from S3 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve both of these goals with APOC. The docs give you two approaches:

- [Load from the GZ file directly](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_load_single_file_from_compressed_file_zip_tar_tar_gz_tgz), assuming the file in the bucket has a public URL
- [Load the file from S3 directly, with an access token](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_s3_protocol)

Here's an example of the first approach - the section after the ! is the filename within the zip file to load, and this should work with `.zip`, `.gz`, `.tar` files etc.

```
CALL apoc.load.csv("https://pablissimo-so-test.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mycsv.zip!mycsv.csv")
```